# How to union two tables with different no of columns?

Tags: sql

This is my query.

```
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,subject,book_id,message from trading_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66)
union
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,message,'A' as subject,'B' as book_id from personal_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66) order by date_added asc
```

And I m getting such error.
Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'

Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't select .. 'A' as subject be select .. subject as 'A' ?

Comment: Another note is your union needs to have the items in the same order as each other... its not smart enough to match the column names, it just looks at values and types.

Comment: @VaheShadunts: yeah it is mysql.

Comment: @cerkiewny: I do not want to alias subject.M aliasing a blank field as subject here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for **MYSQL**.

One of important rules in union: field counts must be equal.

```
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,message, subject,book_id, from trading_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66)
union
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,message,'','' from personal_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66) order by date_added asc
```

NOTE: You don't need for aliases in your second subquery, engine takes fieldnames from your first select result

Comment: Hey there is problem in your query with commas and even after correcting that it does work with blank ' '.It runs in local only but in script it gives error like::
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I ran this for MS Sql Server.  I think one of the problems is that 'B' is being returned as book_id, which I'm *guessing* is an int in the first part of the union query.  As "TheOneWhoPrograms" mentioned columns have to be in order as well.

```
Create Table dbo.trading_message
(
 id int
 ,sender_id int
 ,receiver_id int
 ,date_added datetime
 ,subject varchar(100)
 ,book_id int
 ,message varchar(1000)
)

Create Table dbo.personal_message
(
 id int
 ,sender_id int
 ,receiver_id int
 ,date_added datetime
 ,message varchar(1000)
)

select 
 id
 ,sender_id
 ,receiver_id
 ,date_added
 ,subject
 ,book_id -- <- I *guessing* this is an int
 ,message 
from trading_message 
where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) 
 and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66)

union

select 
 id
 ,sender_id
 ,receiver_id
 ,date_added
 ,'A' as subject
 ,0 as book_id -- <- Changed this from 'B' to zero
 ,message
from personal_message 
where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) 
 and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66) 

order by date_added asc
```

Above has both column(or more specifically) column data types in the same order

Comment: +1 just for the effort you put into this even though it was absolutely not required.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your reply and effort. Yeah i got data but still it is not correct.It is giving repeated data.And i guess this is because of id.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,subject,book_id,message from trading_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66)
union
select id,sender_id,receiver_id,date_added,'A', 'B', null from personal_message where (receiver_id=1132 or receiver_id=66) and (sender_id=1132 or sender_id=66) order by date_added asc
```

Give that a try.. I think I matched up your columns in the right order each having the right amount...

Answer (score -1):

try please set mysql variable instead of char 'A' like

> @var1 AS subject

instead of

> 'A' as subject